# Find out all R contributed packages using a function in a base package

Tags: r, r-package

Is there a way to find out which packages on CRAN are using, for example, `graphics::locator()`?

Comment: It's possible but I don't know any package providing this. You would need to download and parse all NAMESPACE files from packages returned by `devtools::revdep("graphics", c("Imports", "Depends"))`.

Comment: @Roland, you'd also need to read all the code in those packages, because you don't need to mention the function in the `NAMESPACE` file if you call it with the package prefix, i.e. `graphics::locator()`.

Comment: @user2554330 Right, I'm not a fan of using functions without importing them. It's up to OP's cost-benefit analysis if they would want to go that far. The [CRAN mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/cran) might be useful.